# Suppose functions $y$ and $f$ are non-negative and continuous on the interval, prove this inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Suppose functions $y$ and $f$ are non-negative and continuous on the interval $<a,b>$ (where $<$ can be $( $ or $[ $ and $>$ can be $] $ or $) $), and let $\lambda > 0$. If the inequality
> $
> y(x) \leq f(x) + \lambda \Big| \int_{x_0}^x y(s) \, ds \Big|, \quad x, x_0 \in (a,b)
> $
> holds, then
> $
> y(x) \leq f(x) + \lambda \Big| \int_{x_{\uparrow}}^{x} e^{\lambda |x-s|} f(s) \, ds \Big|, \quad \forall x \in (a,b).
> $

How do I go to prove this? My first idea was to use reverse triangle inequality for integrals $\left|\int_{x_{0}}^xg(s)ds\right|\leq\int_{x_{0}}^x\left|g(s)\right|ds$ and $||g(x)|-|g(x_0)||\leq|g(x)-g(x)|\leq \int_{x_{0}}^x\left|g(s)\right|ds$ but I am not sure it gives me anything.

Comment: This is just [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality)

Comment: @JulioPuerta Maybe this is just another formulation but I don't see $\lambda$ in Gronwall's inequality? How can I reformulate my problem to match the formula on Wikipedia?

Comment: Go to integral form for continuous functions, and take $\alpha=f$, $\beta=\lambda$, $u=y$.